# Quickblox: Unable to get push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

I was trying with [This sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android) to receive  push notifications.

But, I tried  from admin's panel, notifications are sent, but I cannot receive  them.

I Have:

1. Checked API key
2. registered device id
3. connected and logged in to my Quickblox account

But still cannot receive  notifications.Any Ideas?

**UPDATE DETAILS:**
ADMINS panel setting:
[image]
QUEUE :

[image]

Google server key:
[image]

devices:
[image]
These devices are visible only if they are subscribed??
 logs:
[image]

**Interesting:** 
It is trying to send push notification :(same device):
[image]

FULL LOG:

```
03-20 22:49:39.169: D/dalvikvm(18976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23860K, 74% free 11915K/44323K, paused 114ms
03-20 22:49:39.199: I/dalvikvm-heap(18976): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.378MB for 7994852-byte allocation
03-20 22:49:39.279: D/dalvikvm(18976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 56% free 19719K/44323K, paused 61ms
03-20 22:49:39.299: D/AbsListView(18976): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
03-20 22:49:39.299: I/MotionRecognitionManager(18976):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@411cc188
03-20 22:49:39.319: D/AbsListView(18976): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
03-20 22:49:39.329: I/MotionRecognitionManager(18976):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@43240b58
03-20 22:49:39.399: D/dalvikvm(18976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 320K, 57% free 19401K/44323K, paused 4ms+15ms
03-20 22:49:39.609: D/dalvikvm(18976): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 26K, 57% free 19375K/44323K, paused 30ms
03-20 22:49:39.619: I/dalvikvm-heap(18976): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.203MB for 17997008-byte allocation
03-20 22:49:39.669: D/dalvikvm(18976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 17% free 36951K/44323K, paused 2ms+4ms
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): =========================================================
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): === REQUEST ==== 08115b17-603e-4685-867b-2e847a64d331 ===
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): REQUEST
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-SDK=Android 1.1.0
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-Token=310b3e298265d13ba263106e89754ee662e2e562
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): PARAMETERS
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     application_id=7467
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     auth_key=TxRFWfX8tTXQ4gv
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     nonce=113269681
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     timestamp=1395335979
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     user[login]=akash_aki
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     user[password]=akash0992
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     signature=663231db5fd380e8a569c94f43832511598b7f48
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): INLINE
03-20 22:49:39.959: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=7467&auth_key=TxRFWfX8tTXQ4gv&nonce=113269681&timestamp=1395335979&user[login]=akash_aki&user[password]=akash0992&signature=663231db5fd380e8a569c94f43832511598b7f48
03-20 22:49:40.009: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18976): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-20 22:49:40.009: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52330000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:59
03-20 22:49:40.189: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x525a7000 size:4608000 offset:3072000 fd:65
03-20 22:49:40.229: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53ff7000 size:6144000 offset:4608000 fd:69
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *********************************************************
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *** RESPONSE *** 08115b17-603e-4685-867b-2e847a64d331 ***
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): STATUS : 201 
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Connection=keep-alive
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Date=Thu, 20 Mar 2014 17:19:47 GMT
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     ETag="e115b558f1e03cab5aa479002da443c7"
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2014-03-20 19:19:47 UTC
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Server=nginx/1.0.15
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Status=201 Created
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Transfer-Encoding=chunked
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Request-Id=7dc72354d68c8b7109de769c057da021
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Runtime=0.027936
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): BODY
03-20 22:49:46.309: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     '{"session":{"_id":"532b2333535c12d80c00316b","application_id":7467,"created_at":"2014-03-20T17:19:47Z","device_id":0,"nonce":113269681,"token":"11d3c6a8c598d8a7a45c40ed3cccf45543357c09","ts":1395335979,"updated_at":"2014-03-20T17:19:47Z","user_id":885926,"id":57955}}'
03-20 22:49:46.329: D/QBASDK QBSessionResult(18976): No onError. All right.
03-20 22:49:46.439: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18976): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-20 22:49:46.439: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x545d3000 size:14921728 offset:14807040 fd:74
03-20 22:49:46.479: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x55534000 size:16457728 offset:16343040 fd:80
03-20 22:49:46.579: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18976): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-20 22:49:46.579: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x564e6000 size:16539648 offset:16457728 fd:83
03-20 22:49:46.609: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18976): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-20 22:49:46.609: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x57c1e000 size:13332480 offset:11796480 fd:92
03-20 22:49:46.639: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x58d02000 size:16621568 offset:16539648 fd:95
03-20 22:49:46.689: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x59cdc000 size:7680000 offset:6144000 fd:98
03-20 22:49:46.729: D/OpenGLRenderer(18976): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-20 22:49:46.729: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52330000 size:1536000 offset:0
03-20 22:49:46.729: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x525a7000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
03-20 22:49:46.729: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53ff7000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
03-20 22:49:46.749: D/OpenGLRenderer(18976): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-20 22:49:46.759: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x545d3000 size:14921728 offset:14807040
03-20 22:49:46.759: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x55534000 size:16457728 offset:16343040
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976): Activity com.quickblox.simplesample.messages.main.activities.SplashActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4334ec30 that was originally added here
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.quickblox.simplesample.messages.main.activities.SplashActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4334ec30 that was originally added here
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:403)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at com.quickblox.simplesample.messages.main.activities.SplashActivity.onComplete(SplashActivity.java:74)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.communication.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:233)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at com.quickblox.internal.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:38)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
03-20 22:49:46.849: E/WindowManager(18976):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 22:49:47.169: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53ff7000 size:9216000 offset:7680000 fd:61
03-20 22:49:47.779: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x55534000 size:16424960 offset:16343040 fd:64
03-20 22:49:52.209: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x564e6000 size:16539648 offset:16457728
03-20 22:49:52.209: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x58d02000 size:16621568 offset:16539648
03-20 22:49:52.209: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x55534000 size:16424960 offset:16343040
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): =========================================================
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): === REQUEST ==== d323f162-2606-481c-9bfc-08fe4993b909 ===
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): REQUEST
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     GET https://api.quickblox.com/users.json
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-SDK=Android 1.1.0
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-Token=11d3c6a8c598d8a7a45c40ed3cccf45543357c09
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): PARAMETERS
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     page=1
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     per_page=100
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): INLINE
03-20 22:50:25.349: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     GET https://api.quickblox.com/users.json?page=1&per_page=100
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *********************************************************
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *** RESPONSE *** d323f162-2606-481c-9bfc-08fe4993b909 ***
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): STATUS : 200 
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Connection=keep-alive
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Date=Thu, 20 Mar 2014 17:20:30 GMT
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     ETag="124b7f5e226dd6a5e3a28d9938e2b30b"
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2014-03-20 19:20:30 UTC
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Server=nginx/1.0.15
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Status=200 OK
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Transfer-Encoding=chunked
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Rack-Cache=miss
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Request-Id=362ba5fb69792a540e54e73a36bdce66
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Runtime=0.026152
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): BODY
03-20 22:50:29.459: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     '{"current_page":1,"per_page":100,"total_entries":9,"items":[{"user":{"id":884167,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"rohan sethi","email":"rohanalone@leavemealone.in","login":"rohanalone","phone":"9654379306","website":null,"created_at":"2014-02-21T16:48:36Z","updated_at":"2014-03-20T16:14:50Z","last_request_at":"2014-03-20T16:14:50Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":885926,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"Akash Yadav","email":"akash0992@gmail.com","login":"akash_aki","phone":"9999097772","website":"http://www.lolo.com","created_at":"2014-02-22T12:58:50Z","updated_at":"2014-03-20T17:19:47Z","last_request_at":"2014-03-20T17:19:47Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":886262,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":null,"email":null,"login":"testlogin","phone":null,"website":null,"created_at":"2014-02-22T15:44:52Z","updated_at":"2014-02-22T15:44:52Z","last_request_at":"2014-02-23T04:14:28Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":888296,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":null,"email":null,"login":"vikas","phone":null,"website":null,"created_at":"2014-02-23T13:30:36Z","updated_at":"2014-02-23T13:30:36Z","last_request_at":"2014-02-24T09:38:54Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":890395,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"vikas vrm","email":"vikasvrm547@gmail.com","login":"vikasss","phone":"9654379306","website":null,"created_at":"2014-02-24T10:36:17Z","updated_at":"2014-02-24T10:36:17Z","last_request_at":"2014-02-24T10:38:49Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":890541,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"test sharma","email":"test@gmail.com","login":"test","phone":"1234567890","website":null,"created_at":"2014-02-24T11:39:30Z","updated_at":"2014-02-24T11:40:36Z","last_request_at":"2014-02-24T12:54:44Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":934942,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"vikas verma","email":"vikasrm547@gmail.com","login":"vikas_verma","phone":"9876543212","website":null,"created_at":"2014-03-12T16:05:01Z","updated_at":"2014-03-20T16:15:48Z","last_request_at":"2014-03-20T16:15:48Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":944455,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":"safs","email":"dsad@gmail.com","login":"aki","phone":"123456789","website":"http://sdsadasd","created_at":"2014-03-17T10:13:32Z","updated_at":"2014-03-17T10:23:58Z","last_request_at":"2014-03-17T10:24:16Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}},{"user":{"id":944456,"owner_id":9064,"full_name":null,"email":null,"login":"hey","phone":null,"website":null,"created_at":"2014-03-17T10:14:41Z","updated_at":"2014-03-17T10:14:41Z","last_request_at":"2014-03-17T10:14:43Z","external_user_id":null,"facebook_id":null,"twitter_id":null,"blob_id":null,"user_tags":null}}]}'
03-20 22:50:29.489: D/QBASDK QBUserPagedResult(18976): No onError. All right.
03-20 22:50:29.549: D/AbsListView(18976): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-20 22:50:29.589: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18976): <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-20 22:50:29.599: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52330000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:67
03-20 22:50:29.669: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x548c1000 size:4608000 offset:3072000 fd:74
03-20 22:50:29.729: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x54d26000 size:6144000 offset:4608000 fd:77
03-20 22:50:31.939: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52330000 size:1536000 offset:0
03-20 22:50:31.939: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x548c1000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
03-20 22:50:31.939: D/memalloc(18976): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x54d26000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): =========================================================
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): === REQUEST ==== 0a6b7c1c-cc7f-46e7-8ebc-bf9f6b9fe7ed ===
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): REQUEST
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/events.json
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-SDK=Android 1.1.0
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     QB-Token=11d3c6a8c598d8a7a45c40ed3cccf45543357c09
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): PARAMETERS
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     event[notification_type]=push
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     event[environment]=development
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     event[user][ids]=885926
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     event[push_type]=GCM
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     event[message]=data.message=&data.type=d2VsY29tZSBtZXNzYWdl
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976): INLINE
03-20 22:50:36.159: D/QBASDK RestRequest(18976):     POST https://api.quickblox.com/events.json?event[notification_type]=push&event[environment]=development&event[user][ids]=885926&event[push_type]=GCM&event[message]=data.message=&data.type=d2VsY29tZSBtZXNzYWdl
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *********************************************************
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): *** RESPONSE *** 0a6b7c1c-cc7f-46e7-8ebc-bf9f6b9fe7ed ***
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): STATUS : 201 
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): HEADERS
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Connection=keep-alive
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Date=Thu, 20 Mar 2014 17:20:41 GMT
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     ETag="df93c493a7d56859abf52538bda2a968"
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2014-03-20 19:20:41 UTC
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Server=nginx/1.0.15
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Status=201 Created
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     Transfer-Encoding=chunked
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Request-Id=7faf1d811112852f3b27a75edf3c5c48
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-Runtime=0.056373
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976): BODY
03-20 22:50:39.839: D/QBASDK RestResponse(18976):     '{"event":{"active":true,"application_id":7467,"created_at":"2014-03-20T17:20:41Z","date":null,"end_date":null,"event_type":"one_shot","id":1194330,"message":"data.message=&data.type=d2VsY29tZSBtZXNzYWdl","name":null,"occured_count":0,"period":null,"updated_at":"2014-03-20T17:20:41Z","user_id":885926,"notification_channel":{"name":"gcm"},"subscribers_selector":{"environment":"development","tags_query":null,"user_ids":[885926]}}}'
03-20 22:50:39.859: D/QBASDK QBEventResult(18976): No onError. All right.
03-20 22:50:39.919: I/System.out(18976): QBEvent{id=1194330, createdAt=Thu Mar 20 22:50:41 IST 2014, updatedAt=Thu Mar 20 22:50:41 IST 2014, active=true, applicationId=7467, date=null, endDate=null, type=one_shot, message='data.message=&data.type=d2VsY29tZSBtZXNzYWdl', name='null', occuredCount=0, period=null, userId=885926, notificationChannel=gcm, subscribersSelector=QBSubscribersSelector{environment=development, tagsQuery=null, userIds=[885926]}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to update the Project Number, available in Google developers console.

Comment: this was a quick save for me! I was struggling and I didn't know where to put the project number but finally got it, just so its more clear for anyone facing the same problem, you need to change the project number within your code to match the project number within the google developers console.

Answer (score 1):

1) Which one API key you use?
Is it a browser key or server key? As I remember you should use browser key. Just try all of them.

2) Check sample log - are all requests were successful?

3) Check zone. If you subscribe user to development zone - you should send development push from admin panel

Comment: Tried all,No success :(

Comment: And even after sending with different keys, the request was successful :/ same thing is happening from 48 hours!

Comment: please provide subscription log from app and screenshot of your Admin panel Messages settings

Comment: Provided the details .Any Ideas?

Comment: It works  fine(See the LOGS) too..So long I am trying to locate the BUG! :/

Comment: It is subscribing  successfully..the `onSuccess` of subscribe also works fine.If you are doing any research, at least  notify me.

Comment: Please try browser key